# Скрипт вывода товаров, очень долго грузится

Tags: mysqli, while, php, foreach

Функции выборки товаров из базы:

```
function result_to_array($result) {
    $res_array = array();
    $count = 0;
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
}

function get_product() {
    connect_db();
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `product` ORDER by `id` DESC");
    $result = result_to_array($result);
    return $result;
}
```

На самой странице все товары выводятся циклом foreach:

```
$products = get_product();

<? foreach ($products as $product): ?>

html код

<? endforeach; ?>
```

Проблема в том, что страница с товарами открывается ну очень долго, раньше просто на этой же самой странице делал запрос и выводил все через while, по скорости было ощутимо быстрее.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и почему так медленно работает скрипт?

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике хрома (вкладка Network) или фаерфокса, что именно у вас так долго грузится, возможно, это не скрипт вывода товаров.

Comment: А какой смысл делать два цикла, когда можно вывести сразу одним?
Если хотите именно функцией сделать, то генерите в ней же html код и возвращайте его функцией в виде строковой переменной.

Comment: Nik555 - в коде RageXL используется подобие MVC.

Comment: Я один увидел бесполезность функции `result_to_array()` ?

Comment: Bastian, нет, я тоже считаю эту функцию бесполезной, мало того, когда данных в запросе будет много, это приведет к замедлению работы скрипта...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А много ли товаров?

И можно оптимизировать конструкцию, убрав `$count`:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $res_array[] = $row;
    }
```

Перед выполнением кода и после выполнения добавьте [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php):

```
function result_to_array($result) {
    $ra_start = microtime();

    $res_array = array();
    $count = 0;
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }

    $ra_end = microtime();
    echo $ra_end - $ra_start;
    return $res_array;
}

function get_product() {
    $gp_start = microtime();

    connect_db();
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `product` ORDER by `id` DESC");
    $result = result_to_array($result);

    $gp_end = microtime();
    echo $gp_end - $gp_start;
    return $result;
}
```

На самой странице все товары выводятся циклом foreach:

```
$products = get_product();

<?
$for_start = microtime();
foreach ($products as $product): ?>
```

html код:

```
<? endforeach;
 $for_end = microtime();
    echo $for_end - $for_start;
?>
```

По результатам сможете увидеть, какой кусок у Вас долго выполняется.

Comment: Товаров около 20, даже пробовал выводить только 5, все равно очень медленно.

Comment: Подправил ответ.

Comment: Результаты тестов, среднее время выполнения: 
function result_to_array($result) - 0.000178
get_product() - 0.008111
foreach ($products as $product) - от 0.4 до 0.9

Comment: Ну вот. Загвоздка скорее всего в "html код". Если несложно, дополните вопрос куском хтмл кода товара.

Comment: В общем, проблема в следующем. В html коде внутри цикла `foreach` вызывается функция, которая определяет имя пользователя, добавившего товар по его id. Если я ее убираю, все работает быстро.

 function get_useronid($id) {
  connect_db();
  global $mysqli;
  $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE id='$id'");
  $row = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
  return $row['login'];
 }   

Сам вызов функции - `<?echo get_useronid($product['user_id']);?>`

Если сделать вот так `<?=$product['user_id']?>`, то все быстро работает.

Comment: Выгребайте имя пользователя одним запросом вместе с информацией по товарам.
{SELECT product.*, users.name FROM `product` inner join users on (product.user_id = user.id) ORDER by `product.id` DESC}

Comment: Все теперь работает. Использовал запрос выше, теперь все как надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Идите поэтапно:

1) Смотрим, а не тупит ли mysql:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `product` ORDER by `id` DESC");
exit();
$result = result_to_array($result);
```

2) Как быстр while:

```
 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $res_array[$count] = $row;
    $count++;
}
exit();
return $res_array;
```

3) Как быстр вызов `$products = get_product();`

```
$products = get_product();
exit();
```

4) Убираем `<? foreach ($products as $product): ?>` и смотрим, как работает  без него.

Если долго выполняеться этап  1, оптимизируем mysql запрос (табличка возможно очень большая).
Если долго выполняеться этап  2, используем ответ выше.
Если долго выполняеться этап  3 (без двух предыдущих ) - что-то очень странное.
Если долго выполняеться этап  4, то используем for вместо foreach  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php).
Если ничего не помогает и вызовы повторяються, то пихаем все в мемкэш (вплоть до html).